# fill in missing values with continous record in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, na, lubridate

I am trying to have a continuous record with `NA` for any missing day.  In my code below I created some `Date` with `Fake Data`. I intentionally removed some days just to reflect my case. I want a continuous record and use NA for Day/Date where i do not have value. For example, `myData` in my code should have the `3rd day` of every month with value as `NA`. This is just an example, i have many `dates/days` missing in my actual data but want to have a continous `date` with value set as `NA` for those missing `dates`

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1500)

DF <-  data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), to = as.Date("2010-12-31"), by = "days"), FakeData = runif(4018, 0,50))


myData <- DF %>% 
  mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date), Day = day(Date)) %>% 
  filter(!Day == 03)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tidyr's `complete` for this, which fills in any rows that are missing from a specified vector (in this case a sequence containing all dates between the first & last dates in your dataframe)

```r
myData %>% 
  complete(Date = seq(first(Date), last(Date), by = "day"))

#> # A tibble: 4,018 x 5
#>    Date       FakeData  Year Month   Day
#>    <date>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#>  1 2000-01-01     31.2  2000     1     1
#>  2 2000-01-02     48.6  2000     1     2
#>  3 2000-01-03     NA      NA    NA    NA
#>  4 2000-01-04     17.1  2000     1     4
#>  5 2000-01-05     15.5  2000     1     5
#>  6 2000-01-06     12.9  2000     1     6
#>  7 2000-01-07     19.8  2000     1     7
#>  8 2000-01-08     48.1  2000     1     8
#>  9 2000-01-09     47.5  2000     1     9
#> 10 2000-01-10     40.7  2000     1    10
#> # … with 4,008 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can `merge` `myData` with `DF` to get all the days with `NA` appended

```
merge(DF[-2], myData, all.x = TRUE)

#       Date FakeData Year Month Day
#1 2000-01-01 31.19773 2000     1   1
#2 2000-01-02 48.61096 2000     1   2
#3 2000-01-03       NA   NA    NA  NA
#4 2000-01-04 17.11499 2000     1   4
#5 2000-01-05 15.52981 2000     1   5
#6 2000-01-06 12.92870 2000     1   6
#....
```

In case you don't have access to `DF` you can generate one by :

```
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(min(myData$Date), max(myData$Date), by = 'day'))
```